# Access file using correct syntax

Tags: batch-file

I want to access a file with correct path as

"C:\Win10 LTSC GOA 2022-04\Step 3 - Install Adobe Reader DC\Installer\Full_Setup_adobe_DC.bat"

My batch file is stored in same directory but different folder : "C:\Win10 LTSC GOA 2022-04\Batches"

When write the code in batch I use

```
 start "" "%~dp0Step 3 - Install Adobe Reader DC\Installer\Full_Setup_adobe_DC.bat"
```

[image]

The error dialogue box shows wrong path

"C:\Win10 LTSC GOA 2022-04\Batches\Step 3 - Install Adobe Reader DC\Installer\Full_Setup_adobe_DC.bat"

What should be the right syntax %~dp0, %~D0 should be used in this case ??

Comment: If I understand correctly, try: ```@Call "%~dp0..\Step 3 - Install Adobe Reader DC\Installer\Full_Setup_adobe_DC.bat"```.

Comment: Bingo. Thanks a lot . Meantime, please see if you can help me on this question https://superuser.com/questions/1750641/search-file-to-locate-the-drive

Comment: Only if the originating code was written by myself, exists on StackOverflow, and you link and reference it in a new question on also on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

`My batch file is stored in same directory but different folder : "C:\Win10 LTSC GOA 2022-04\Batches"`

"folder" is thr name the command-line-challenged use for "directory".

`%~dp0` and `%~DP0` are equivalent. Batch commands are largely case-insensitive, except for the `metavariable` in a `for` statement (`for %%x` and `for %%X` refer to different metavariables, and are not interchangeable)

`%~dp0` means `the **d**rive and **p**ath of the **current** directory.` %d0` means simply the **d**rive. I presume that's a typo in your question.

```
start "" "C:\Win10 LTSC GOA 2022-04\Batches\Full_Setup_adobe_DC.bat"
```

should work, but since your starting directory is `C:\Win10 LTSC GOA 2022-04\Batches` then `%~dp0` is resolved to `C:\Win10 LTSC GOA 2022-04\Batches\` and the `Step 3 - Install Adobe Reader DC\Installer\Full_Setup_adobe_DC.bat` is appended - giving you the reported "can't find" message.

Comment: How can I extract the drive and directory from %~dp0

Comment: If  %~dp0 = C:\Win10 LTSC GOA 2022-04\Batches\, how can I extract just the drive and directory : C:\Win10 LTSC GOA 2022-04\ . Should I use something like   for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=\" %%G in (%~dp0) do echo %%G

Comment: Not quite. In general, you wouldn't know how many backslashes to remove. `for %%b in ("%~dp0.") do set "parentdirectory=%%~dpb"` should always work. `%~dp0` is the drive and path with terminal backslash. Append a `.` and the resultant string is resolved without that terminal backslash, which looks just like a filename, so its drive and path is the parent drive and path. I recommend to remove the backslash (`set "parentdirectory=%parentdirectory:~0,-1%"` on a new line) as it is generally easier to insert the backslashes as desired than remove them when not desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your advice inspire me to use more options in %~dp. 